# Are codegen units automatically decreased to 16 if [build]incremental is set to false in cargo.config?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Do I need to set [profile.dev] codegen-units = 16 in Cargo.toml?

I read the Cargo documentation and expected to know a clear answer to my question
All I read is that the default codegen units is 16 for non incremental builds. But it also says that the default value for [profile.dev] codegen-units is 256. I'm not sure if they are overridden to 16

Comment: "The default value, if not specified, is 16 for non-incremental builds. For incremental builds, the default is 256 ...". Those numbers (16 and 256) are defaults, if you provide a value, 16 and 256 are ignored. In order to override, you need to set them in profiles (dev, build, test, bench, or your personal ones)

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#codegen-units